# MATCH a cell value, then return the value of the cell next to it

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup

Is there a way to use a `MATCH` formula to look up where one value appears and then use that returned index as the point to reference to find another value?

Right now I have a spreadsheet set up where I have a list of project ID's (column A)and column B has the category that each project falls into. Now I need to reference those projects on other sheets, and every time I do that I would like to pull up the appropriate column B value.

I tried this to get where on the projects list it is called:

```
=MATCH(C16,'Projects List'!A1:A)
```

and that is pulling in the index of that project in the list. Now I want to look one column over to that and get the corresponding job category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- use **`VLOOKUP`** for that:

  ```
  =VLOOKUP(C1, A:B, 2, 0)
  ```
- for the whole column:

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C:C, A:B, 2, 0)))
  ```

  [image: 0]

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I'm looking to do.